# How to remove duplicating character from beginning of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a an array of human-entered numbers which contain random amount of zeros before actual number begins.
guess example will say more:

```
entry_1="0000005452508"
entry_2="02965054"
entry_3="5487864"
```

I need to get the string after these duplicating zeros end, i.e first entry should result in 5452508. Numbers of digits if not fixed. Lists are enormously huge, so I need something nice and fast to work here.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: How are you going to use these numbers? Is any arithmetic involved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) does what you want:

```
entry_1 = "0000005452508".lstrip("0")
entry_2 = "02965054".lstrip("0")
entry_3 = "5487864".lstrip("0")
```

Comment: If you want to remove the repetitions of first character even if it is not a `0` you can use `if entry_1: entry_1 = entry_1.lstrip(entry_1[0])`

Comment: The modified version of @juankysmith fails at empty strings (just to point out a possible flaw).

Comment: There is one edge case to be aware of: `"0".lstrip("0")` gives the empty string, but you probably want `"0"` in that case. Perhaps `entry = entry.lstrip("0") or "0"`

Comment: Works good, ended up with .lstrip("0 ") string which deletes zeros and accidential blank spaces. Thanks a lot, dav1d!

Answer (score 3):

`lstrip`, as suggested by [@dav1d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12260400/140816) is *definitely* the way to go.

With regex, you *could* use the following to accomplish the same:

```
> import re
> re.sub("^0+", "", "0000005452508")
"5452508"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `.lstrip` as has already been suggested, but if you really wanted a regex.

Sub leading zeroes with nothing:

```
re.sub(r'^0*', '', entry_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answers have already been provided, but **all are creating a new sequence**. To offer an alternative, since you have specified that your lists are huge and copying could thus be an issue, you should consider using [`itertools.dropwhile`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

> Make an iterator that drops elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true; afterwards, returns every element.

For example:

```
import itertools
itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == '0', entry_1)
```